# Отличие Equals от Contains

Tags: java

Всем привет! Подскажите плиз в чём отличие функции сравнения строк equals от contains???

Comment: я не знаком с java, но по-моему, из названия очевидно, что contains не должна сравнивать строки

Comment: javadoc читать пробовали?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
"text text".equals("text") // false
"text text".contains("text") // true
```

Equals - являются ли строки одинаковыми

Contains -  содержит ли одна строка другую

Comment: можно добавить, что математически:

    equals(x,y) = x.contains(y) and y.contains(x)

Comment: Можно и не математическое. Строки "Пошёл" и "Пошёл на $%#!" Вторая содержит (contains) первую, но не эквивалентна ей